# Submit to journal and poster session at conference simultaneously in social science

Tags: etiquette, social-science

In social science are you allowed to submit to a journal and conference (poster session) at the same time? The conference I'm looking at does not indicate that you can't post your results elsewhere, and  none of the poster sessions from previous years are indexed on Google Scholar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are allowed to. The social sciences use conferences to present work in progress, and do not count as publications like they do in computer science.

Comment: Similarly, am I allowed to submit to multiple conferences at the same time?

Comment: @ral Check the guidelines for each conference.

Comment: You are allowed to do so, but it is not really a good idea. As Azor Ahai mentioned the purpose of a conference in the social sciences is to present work in progress. This means, you get feedback, and use that to improve your work. If you already published it, then the feedback is just a waste of time for you and the person giving you that feedback. Typically, you first present your work at a conference. You use the feedback to improve your work, and than publish it in a journal.

Comment: @ral Usually not. Also not a good use of money. But it is not uncommon to present a later iteration of a work at a different conference.